# Selecting only even numbers in php output

Tags: php

I am trying to select and display only the even number in a separate output from this below

```
 function toms($c,$first = 0,$second = 1)
 {
     $toms = [$first,$second];
     for($i=1;$i<$c;$i++)
     {
         $toms[] = $toms[$i]+$toms[$i-1];
     }
     return $toms;
 }
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r(toms(33));
 ?>
```

currently this outputs

```
 array
 (
     [0] => 0
     [1] => 1
     [2] => 1
     [3] => 2
     [4] => 3
     [5] => 5
     [6] => 8
     [7] => 13
     [8] => 21
      [9] => 34
     [10] => 55
     [11] => 89
     [12] => 144
     [13] => 233
     [14] => 377
     [15] => 610
     [16] => 987
     [17] => 1597
     [18] => 2584
     [19] => 4181
     [20] => 6765
     [21] => 10946
     [22] => 17711
     [23] => 28657
     [24] => 46368
     [25] => 75025
     [26] => 121393
     [27] => 196418
     [28] => 317811
     [29] => 514229
     [30] => 832040
     [31] => 1346269
     [32] => 2178309
     [33] => 3524578
)
```

Anyone know how I can display only the even numbers returned, so I would want to have 2, 8, 34 and so on

thank you

Comment: do you have to use print_r?  You could just use a loop to iterate across `toms` and only print out the even numbers.

Comment: Do you wish to just list positive even numbers (not including zero)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter)

```
print_r(array_filter(toms(33), function($number){
    return $number % 2 == 0;
}));
```

Or if you want to filter out `0`:

```
print_r(array_filter(toms(33), function($number){
    return $number != 0 && $number % 2 == 0;
}));
```

A bit more readable:

```
$isEvenNumber = function($number) {
    return $number % 2 == 0;
}

$numbers = toms(33);

$filtered_numbers = array_filter($numbers, $isEvenNumber);

var_dump($filtered_numbers);
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you :) and cheers for commenting so fast

Comment: `0 % 2 === 0`, so no problem.  Zero is an even number.

Comment: @Progrock: Agreed, I was going by OP _2, 8, 34 and so on_